# Обрамление слов - умная обработка + экранирование

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

Пытаюсь реализовать `MARKDOWN`, но столкнулся с проблемой: если подставить вот так: `##foo#` или `##foo#####`, то всё ломается, и нет возможности экранировать.

Как добиться результата как здесь, на *StackOverflow*: при обрамлении кода есть возможность даже экранировать `foo`?

Регулярное выражение, по которому происходит обрамление: `/#(.*?)#/`

Сам код:

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var hint = document.getElementById('hint');

text.oninput = function() {
    make();
}
text.onclick = function() {
    make();
}
text.onkeyup = function() {
    make();
}

function make() {
    hint.innerHTML = text.value.replace(/#(.*?)#/g, "<b>$1</b>");
}
```

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
#hint {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
i {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
b {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#text {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="hint">—</div>
  <textarea id="text" cols="50" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae natus #data# possimus ut consequuntur atque officia, #@KEYWORD# est nesciunt delectus sit veritatis eius, sunt hic, provident sapiente repellendus quaerat pariatur recusandae!</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно, особенно с учетом данных ответов - уточните вопрос, прриведите конкретные примеры и что не получается

Comment: Четко сформулируйте задачу. Несмотря на то, что я каждый день пользуюсь маркдаун и регулярными выражениями я не понимаю чего Вы хотите. Приведите разнообразные примеры текста и как они должны быть обработаны. Ознакомьтесь с разделом «Как задать вопрос про регулярные выражения» в метке [tag:регулярные-выражения].

Answer (score 2):

Включу режим телепата и предложу захват всех рядом стоящих решеток вокруг символов, если внутри нет пробелов

```
/#+([^#\s]+)#+/g
```

**UPD** Вот другой зубодробильный вариант

```
/(^|\s)(#+)([^#\s]*[^#\\])(\2)(?=\s)/g
```

применять так

```
.replace(/(^|\s)(#+)([^#\s]*[^#\\])(\2)(?=\s)/g, "$1<b>$3</b>");
```

Результат

```
#foobar# - обрамляет, 
###foobar### - обрамляет, 
#foobar### - не обрамляет, 
\#foobar\# - не обрамляет, 
\#foobar\### - не обрамляет,

#foobar\# - не обрамляет,
#\# - не обрамляет
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/yR1kL5/2

**UPD2** Вариант регулярного выражения от @ReinRaus

```
/(^|\s)(#+)((?:\\.|[^#\\])+)\2(?=\s)/g
```

применять так

```
.replace(/(^|\s)(#+)((?:\\.|[^#\\])+)\2(?=\s)/g, "$1<b>$3</b>");
```

Результат

```
#f\#\#\#\#\#\#\#oobar# - обрамляет, 
###foo\#bar### - обрамляет, 
#foobar### - не обрамляет, 
\#foobar\# - не обрамляет, 
\#foobar\### - не обрамляет,

#foobar\# - не обрамляет,
#\# - не обрамляет
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/yR1kL5/3

Comment: `\#` нужна возможность экранирования

Comment: @maschine, пример что ли приведите, а то это `\# нужна возможность экранирования` на русский язык перевести не могу.

Comment: обрамление кода или других ключевых фраз осуществляется с помощью символов `. если экранировать их, то просто добавятся сами символы - \`foobar\`

Comment: @maschine, то есть вам надо реализовать такой бб-код, внутри которого другие бб-коды не действуют?

Comment: `#foobar#` - обрамлять, `###foobar###` - обрамлять, `#foobar###` - не обрамлять(выводить решетки), `\#foobar\#` - не обрамлять(выводить решетки), `\#foobar\###` - не обрамлять(выводить решетки)

Comment: в ответе выше ссылка, только обратите внимание, что по стандарту надо экранировать каждый символ: `\#foobar\#\#\#`

Comment: @11111000000, автор вопроса не хочет стандарт, а хочет парсер. Эту строку `#\#Quae\#####` обрамлять парсер не должен, в то время как сейчас он у вас ее обрамляет.

Comment: парсеры я за деньги пишу, обращайтесь )  а регулярку теоритически можно и такую написать, чтобы \## меняла на :HASH::HASH:, если действительно надо

Comment: @maschine, обновил ответ.

Comment: меня интересует `markdown`, а именно экранирование в нем.. почему если написать `\#foobar#`, то есть заэкранировать первый символ, то обрамление не происходит, как при обрамление символом - `

Comment: @maschine, в вопросе у вас речь про регулярное выражение, в тегах у вас регулярное выражение. Я вам написал регулярное выражение, которое соответствует вашему уточняющему комментарию. Что не так? Интересует вас `markdown` читайте умные книги и задавайте правильно сформулированные вопросы!

Comment: @Visman: +1 вашему мэдскил

Comment: @ReinRaus, на моем тесте посмотрите. С вашей регуляркой что-то не то происходит ;) P.S. Я писал регулярное выражение для обрамление слова тегами `<b>` и `</b>` с уточняющим комментарием автора к моему ответу под номером 5.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ответ дополнил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот регулярка, лишённая описанной вами проблемы с повторными `#` (но не лишённая других):

```
hint.innerHTML = text.value.replace(/[#]+(.*?)[#]+/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

Вообще эту задачу, как и любой парсер, логичнее всего решать через конечный автомат - это хотя и скурпулёзная работа, но сильно экономит нервы. Однако, есть и другие способы. Вот простые примеры:

1. http://pzxc.com/simple-javascript-markdown-parsing-function
2. https://github.com/Khan/simple-markdown

Update:

Если в вашем стиле продолжить, то вот так можно реализовать экранирование:

```
function make() {
  var html = text.value;
   html = html
            .replace(/\\#/g,'::HASH::')
            .replace(/[#]+(.*?)[#]+/g, "<b>$1</b>")
            .replace(/::HASH::/g,'#');
   hint.innerHTML = html
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/11111000000/30pvaphe/1/

Comment: этот вариант поддерживает в т.ч. `#\#Quae\#####`

Comment: Никогда не пишите так. В регулярных выражениях есть простой способ работать с экранированными символами.