# Markdown - парсинг слов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь завернуть слово, как это делается в Markdown, но не получается до конца. При использовании такой конструкции: `str.value.replace(/(^|\b|\s)#(.*?)#(\b|\s)/gm, "<h3>$2</h3>");` - все заворачивается, но опять же - не как в Markdown: при экранировании показывает сам слэш-символ, при обрамлении количество решеток должно быть одинаково с обеих сторон... Я даже приведу вам [отрывок из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown):

> *Символы, которые обычно рассматриваются в Markdown как специальные, могут быть экранированы с помощью обратного слеша. Например, последовательность «\*» выведет символ «*», а не будет являться признаком начала выделенного текста.*

в общем, как как правильно это делается через регулярные выражения?

PS. Просьба не кидать линки для громоздкие Markdown-библиотеки. Интересно знать самому.

Comment: Makedown, Makerdown, Markdown...определитесь, пожалуйста. И составлять обработчики разметки из регулярных выражений -- гиблая идея. UPD: спасибо.

Comment: как еще иначе их делать??

Comment: Регулярками вычленять конструкции, собирать из них синтаксическое дерево и рендерить в результат. Так, например, делает [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked/blob/master/lib/marked.js), код которого не слишком крупный.

Comment: Лабораторку что-ли студентам задали... Сегодня же, в аналогичном вопросе ("_Обрамление слов - умная обработка + экранирование_"),  уже привел ссылки на __легковесные__ примеры реализации. Плюс, там же приведён и понятный код, как экранирование реализовать на __регулярках__, а именно - заменить сначала на ключевые слова, а затем, после обработки неэкранированых символов - обратно. Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обрамление слов - умная обработка + экранирование](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450246/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Четко сформулируйте задачу. Несмотря на то, что я каждый день пользуюсь маркдаун и регулярными выражениями я не понимаю чего Вы хотите. Приведите разнообразные примеры текста и как они должны быть обработаны. Ознакомьтесь с разделом «Как задать вопрос про регулярные выражения» в метке [tag:регулярные-выражения].

Answer (score 3):

"Правильно" это не делается через регулярные выражения вообще. Регулярные выражения - это очень удобный, но весьма ограниченный инструмент для парсинга различных шаблонных конструкций. Если вы и составите регулярку на весь маркдаун целиком, то она, скорее всего, займет несколько килобайт (в средней официальности спецификации одних только уточняющих примеров разметки больше двухсот штук), и работать с этим будет невозможно; кроме того, помимо выделения самих блоков разметки, нужно еще и преобразование - например, убрать те самые слеши.

"Правильно" - это анализ документа, построение дерева встречающихся в документе боков и преобразование этого дерева в новый текстовый документ. Сначала необходимо разбить документ на отдельные токены (в случае `> *text*` получится четыре токена - символ цитаты `>`, символ начала выделенного текста `*`, произвольный текстовый токен `text` и еще один `*`), после чего нужно проанализировать эти токены и объединить их в дерево, состоящее из блоков (в том же примере получится дерево из одной ветви: цитата - выделенние - произвольный текст), и, наконец, по полученному дереву построить готовый документ (с html это очень просто, потому что необходимо просто идти по дереву и открывать и закрывать теги при начале и конце узла).

Существуют автоматические генераторы парсеров для регулярных языков (bison, yacc - правда, они совсем не для яваскрипта), но здесь, боюсь, я уже ничего не подскажу.

Comment: Видел бизоноподобный инструмент на JS. Ищущий да обрящет.

Comment: `это очень просто` - можете для примера привести маленький кусок кода, если возможно?

Comment: @rain `функция рендер(узел) { тег(узел).открыть(); для_всех(у в узел.содержимое) {рендер(у);} тег(узел).закрыть(); }`