# Условие в php шаблонизаторе

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы, условия

Решил для общего развития написать свой велосипед-шаблонизатор.
Дано: Шаблон. Переменные в хтмл коде вписываются в формате `{var}`, `{name}`, `{id}` итд. 
Шаблонизатору на вход подаётся ассоциативный массив с переменными (ключ - имя переменной в шаблоне). С помощью `preg_replace` произвожу замену.

Ступор начался когда попытался реализовать условия:

```
{if id == 3}
код...
{else}
другой код...
{endif}
```

Пытался подсмотреть в разных шаблонизаторах как реализован такой функционал, но не до конца понял. Может кто то делал подобное, или на примере существующих шаблонизаторов\фреймворков подскажет в какую сторону двигаться?

Comment: `/\{\s*if\s+(?P<var>\w+)\s*==\s*(?P<value>\}(код)(\{\s*else\s*\}(<другой код>))?\{\s*endif\s*\}` - это что касается именно регулярки (мог где-то со скобками напутать)

Comment: где-то, кажется, был более подробный ответ, пока так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450332/16095

Comment: покажите нерабочий код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы меня заинтриговали, мне стало интересно, а решается ли это простыми методами, без полного разбора на лексемы, сверхсложных регулярок и т.п. Я исходил из предположения, что структуры `{if}` могут быть вложенными, иначе задача решалась слишком просто. Условия для `if` лучше пусть остается простым, как вы написали, иначе без полного синтаксического анализа не обойтись.

В итоге случайно написал рабочий пример :)

```
function testIF($text)
 {
  if(preg_match('/(?<pre>.*?)\{if +(?<p1>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*) *(?<op>[=!><]+) *(?<p2>.*?) *\}(?<post>.*)/s',
                $text,$match)):
    // Корректная конструкция IF встретилась. В $match следующие элементы:
    // "pre" - текст до IF,  "post" - текст после IF
    // "p1" параметр IF до кода операции, "p2" параметр после кода операции
    // "op" код операции
    // Регулярка предполагает, что до кода операции именно название переменной
    // А коды операций могут состоять из символов =, !, <, >
    // Если это может быть не так - регулярку стоит поправить

     $t=testIF($match['post']); // Вызываем себя рекурсивно, для обработки вложенных if
      // В $t вернется весь текст за нашим if, в котором все вложенные if
      // уже обработаны, т.е. заменены на текст по условию
     $pos=strpos($t,"{endif}");
     // Действия при ошибке, конечно стоит сделать более разумными, не завершая программу
     if($pos===FALSE): print("Syntax error endif not found for ..."); die(); endif;
     $post=substr($t,$pos+7); // $post - текст после endif
     $t=substr($t,0,$pos);    // Внутренний блок if
     $els="";
     if(preg_match('/(.*?)\{else\}(.*)/s',$t,$m2)): $t=$m2[1]; $els=$m2[2]; endif;

     // Обрабатываем параметры, обработка конечно должна быть более развернутой, с проверкой
     // на существование переменных, на то а переменные ли это или константы
     $p1=$VARS[$match['p1']];
     $p2=$match['p2'];
     switch($match['op']) // Обработка операций
      { // Если условие не прошло, то заменяем текст $t на блок {else}, если был или пустоту
       case "==": if($p1 != $p2) $t=$els; break;
       case "!=": if($p1 == $p2) $t=$els; break;
      }
     return $match['pre'].$t.$post;
  endif;
  return $text;
 }
```

Comment: Ну до вложеных я пока не дошёл. Делаю по нарастающей. При ошибке (синтаксис кривой в шаблоне) оставлять как есть. Так вроде большинство шаблонизаторов поступают.

Comment: Если что, у меня тут нет цикла по нескольким отдельным IF в одном тексте. Цикл заменяет та же рекурсия, которая отвечает за вложенные конструкции. 2 в одном :)

Answer (score 1):

Текст разбивается на лексемы, на основе лексем пишутся правила.
Вот токенизатор из твига https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Lexer.php
У страуступа в книжке по С++ написано о лексемах хорошо, когда калькулятор программируешь